# Как использовать switch-case с фактически статичными данными?

Tags: java, static, switch

Есть вот такой класс для хранения:

```java
public class CommandsIntentions {
    static Command ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE = new Command(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "CREATE"}, DataCommands.ChannelCreate.class);
    static Command ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_JOIN = new Command(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "USERS", "JOIN"}, DataCommands.ChannelUsersJoin.class);
    static Command ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_APPEND = null; // TODO
    static Command USER_CHANNELS_MESSAGES_POST_NEW = new Command(new String[]{"USER", "CHANNELS", "MESSAGES", "POST", "NEW"}, DataCommands.ChannelMessagesPostNew.class);
}
```

В качестве оболочек хранения выступают:

```java
public class Command {
    String[] intents;
    Class pattern;

    public Command (String[] intents, Class pattern) {
        this.intents = intents;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
}
```

Вот и делаю обращение:

```
@Override
public void onMessage (WebSocket webSocket, String message) {
    Helper.MessagePacket packet = Helper.parsePacket(message);

    switch (packet.intention) {
        case CommandsIntentions.ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE.intents -> {
            break;
        }
        default -> {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Но выдаётся ошибка:

```
Constant expression required: 42
```

Так же прилагаю парсинг пакета:

```java
public static class MessagePacket {
    final String hash;
    final String[] intention;
    final String preData;
    Object postData;

    public MessagePacket (String[] intention, String controlSum, String data) {
        this.intention = intention;
        this.hash = controlSum;
        this.preData = data;
    }

    public void parseData (Class pattern) {
        postData = JsonIterator.deserialize(preData, pattern);
    }
}

@Contract("_ -> new")
public static @NotNull MessagePacket parsePacket (@NotNull String packet) {
    String[] splitPacket = packet.split("%");

    return new MessagePacket(splitPacket[0].split("-"), splitPacket[1], splitPacket[2]);
}
```

[image: IDEA]

Comment: Так а `packet.intention` - это что? Строка или объект какого-то другого класса?

Comment: Сейчас отредактирую вопрос.

Comment: @Byb, добавил парсер.

Comment: Чисто в теории, мне может помочь `record`. Но у него атрибуты приватные... Есть ли способ сделать их публичными?

Comment: Ошибка `"Constant expression required"` возникает, когда константа неправильно задана. Переведи это просто на `if-else`

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко, это я понял и сам. Другой вопрос. Откуда?

Comment: А `if-else` - это очень тяжёлые операции, особенно с учётом того, что я использую массивы.

Comment: @mister_svinia сделай их константами `final` иначе как ты хочешь работать не будет.

Comment: @mister_svinia я ещё раз посмотрел твой код и честно говоря вопрос возник. 
А почему ты решил, что ты сможешь массивы в `switch` запихнуть? переменная `intention` у тебя строковой массив, а `switch` вроде как не умеет сравнивать массивы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть большое желание использовать именно `switch`, то можно переписать класс `Command` как перечисление (`enum`) с нужными полями и методом для получения экземпляра по массиву интентов, поскольку значения в перечислениях являются константными по определению:

```java
public enum Command {
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "CREATE"}, DataCommands.ChannelCreate.class),
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_JOIN(new String[]{"ADMIN", "CHANNELS", "USERS", "JOIN"}, DataCommands.ChannelUsersJoin.class),
    ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_APPEND(new String[0], null), // TODO
    USER_CHANNELS_MESSAGES_POST_NEW(new String[]{"USER", "CHANNELS", "MESSAGES", "POST", "NEW"}, DataCommands.ChannelMessagesPostNew.class);

    private final String[] intents;
    private final Class pattern;

    private Command(String[] intents, Class pattern) {
        this.intents = intents;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    // ... геттеры / toString ...

    // пример реализации -- сравниваются массивы целиком
    public static Command byIntents(String[] intents) {
        return Arrays.stream(Command.values())
            .filter(v -> Arrays.equals(v.intents, intents))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    }
}
```

Cоответственно, обращение к такой команде может выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
@Override
public void onMessage (WebSocket webSocket, String message) {
    Helper.MessagePacket packet = Helper.parsePacket(message);

    Command cmd = Command.byIntents(packet.intention); 
    switch (cmd) {
        case ADMIN_CHANNELS_CREATE, ADMIN_CHANNELS_USERS_JOIN -> {
            System.out.println("Команда админа: " + cmd);
        }
        default -> {
            System.out.println("Неизвестная команда, пока что не обрабатывается " + cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Хотел бы заметить, что `break` используется в классическом операторе `switch` (где после `case` используется двоеточие), чтобы код "не проваливался" через разные метки в "кейсах".
При использовании "нового" синтаксиса `switch`-выражений (со стрелкой после `case`) оператор `break` *в данном случае* не нужен (нет цикла, из которого следовало бы выйти заранее).

Comment: Я, пожалуй, вообще откажусь от сплита. Изначально в нём вроде как был смысл, но после того, как я понял способ таскания шаблонов классов...